# OpenCV C++: Floodfill

Tags: c++, opencv

I got this image and I'd like to fill the upper left black area with white, but all I get is a completely white image … Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

**Code:**

```
...
cv::Rect rect;
roi = cv::floodFill(roi, cv::Point(1,1), cv::Scalar(0), &rect, cv::Scalar(0), cv::Scalar(0), 4);
...
```

**Input image:**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the image I get with the following code:

```
int main()    
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("TF2XE.jpg", -1);    
    cv::imshow("image before filling", image);    
    int filling = cv::floodFill(image, cv::Point(0,0), 255, (cv::Rect*)0, cv::Scalar(), 200);   
    cv::imshow("image after filling", image);    
    cv::waitKey();    
    return 0;    
}
```

[image: Output image]

Notice that I used 200 as upDiff parameter, since if you set it to 0 there will be some gray pixels that will not be considered inside the connected component, change that if that is indeed what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but according to the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html) I was able to dig up, it says that `cv::floodFill()` returns an `int`. So assuming that `roi` is a matrix and the openCV matrix class defines `operator=` for `int` parameters, you could be assigning some `int` to each element of the matrix.